# SSRS Date Part Month Grouping

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I currently have a stored procedure for showing sales per day for a year, the field is just a date time field, is there a way I can group by just the month with in a SSRS Matrix without having to amend the stored procedure to show the month?

Thanks

Comment: Go to the grouping property  and add =Month(Your Field)

Comment: Hi Snowlockk, I ended up using =Format(CDate(Fields!A.Value), "MMMM yyyy") as I wanted to include the year as well but both options work well for me :)  thanks